# Reverse proxy SSL problems

Tags: apache2, 18.04, proxy, ssl

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 although couldn't I get it to work with Ubuntu 16.04 either. I'm running apache 2.4.29 and openssl 1.1.0g.

I'm trying to setup a reverse proxy that worked with Ubuntu 14, and getting these errors:

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /testserver.
Reason: Error reading from remote server
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at 172.16.0.140 Port 443

From the log
[Tue May 29 09:14:36.494710 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 23700:tid 139947205977856] SSL Library Error: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

when trying to connect via a browser

also getting these errors from the command line on the backend

openssl s_client -connect 1804-testserver.local:443
CONNECTED(00000003)139763485823424:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:252:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 176 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1527795715
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))